# Mixed java and scala maven project does not run

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a mixed java and scala Maven project that I am trying to package. However while trying to run the java main class it throws the error "Could not find or load main class". I have been trying to understand how a mixed project compiles and packages and I was able to find some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448582/my-mixed-scala-java-maven-project-doesnt-compile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836905/maven-mixing-java-and-scala-in-one-project). However, these are old answers and the solutions are not working well for me.

Can someone help me with a modern solution?

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible code in your question.